# Probability that first born is a boy

Tags: probability

I had this question on an exam last week: there is a family, and they have $3$ children, you know that they have exactly $2$ boys and $1$ girl. What is the probability that the first born is a boy?

Some people answered $1/2$ and others $2/3$, what do you think? We can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) for conditional probability problems:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

In this case, the events A and B are:

A: **first born is boy**

B: **family have exactly two boys, one girl**

Bayes' Theorem then states for this problem that:

> The probability of the first born being a boy given that the family has two boys and a girl is:
>
> the probability that the family has two boys and a girl given the first born is male, times the probability the first born is a boy, divided by the probability the family has two boys and a girl.

Each of the probabilities needed can be calculated:

$$
\begin{align}
P(B|A)&=P(\text{the family has two boys and a girl|the first born is male})=\frac12\\
P(A)&=P(\text{first born is a boy})=\frac12\\
P(B)&=P(\text{the family has two boys and a girl})=\frac38
\end{align}
$$

Putting these together gives:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{\frac12\frac12}{\frac38}=\frac23$$

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities are: `bbg` `bgb` `gbb`

Favorable: `bbg` `bgb`

Answer (score 0):

The three different possibilities are BGB - BBG - GBB => Probability of a boy first is two thirds.

Another way to look at it: call the children X,Y,Z, with Y and Z males, and X female. So what is the probability that X is first? It's 1/3, since they are all equally likely to come up first. So with probability 2/3 the first one is either Y or Z, i.e. a male.

Comment: Thank you! This will clear out a lot of discussions!